# after deploy mean stack project on heroku it work only when local server running if close local server

Tags: node.js, angular, express, heroku, mlab

after deploy mean stack on heroku in work good if local server running but if i close local server get error "POST http://localhost:4000/api/newcontact net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED " and how it work with localhost after deploying

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you might be using  http://localhost:4000 in the services. Change it to the URL where your API is actually hosted.